# consulta sql parametrizada

Tags: sql-server

Escriba una consulta que muestre el apellido (con la primera letra en mayúsculas y las demás en minúsculas) y la longitud del apellido de todos los empleados cuyo nombre comience por L, P o R. Etiquete cada columna de forma adecuada. Ordene los resultados por los apellidos de los empleados.

ya tengo todo excepto la parte de la longitud este es el codigo que tengo:

```
SELECT UPPER(LEFT(apellido, 1)) + LOWER(SUBSTRING(apellido, 2, LEN(apellido))) as apellidos 
FROM empleados 
where apellido LIKE 'L%' OR 
      apellido LIKE 'P%' OR 
      apellido LIKE 'R%' 
group by apellido  
having count (*) >= 1 
ORDER BY apellido
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hice algunos cambios a tu consulta:

```
SELECT UPPER(LEFT(apellido, 1)) + LOWER(SUBSTRING(apellido, 2, LEN(apellido))) as apellidos,
    LEN(apellido) AS 'LongitudApellido' 
    FROM empleados 
    where apellido LIKE '[LPR]%'
    GROUP BY apellido
    ORDER BY apellido
```

1. La longitud de cualquier cadena la obtienes con la función [`LEN()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/len-transact-sql)
2. No es que estuviera mal, pero modifique el LIKE simplemente para que sea más corto, funciona igual.

Comment: muchas gracias hermano